# pendrive is appearing and disappearing

Tags: usb-flash-drive, fat32

My pendrive is recognized on every computer but it will appear and after some time will disappear causing windows to show a FAT32 error.

In Windows XP it says that the hardware is damaged. This happens within 2-3 seconds so I'm not able to format it.

In XP the properties for it shows zero space and in windows 7 it properly shows the disk space.

I don't know what exactly happened to it because I gave it to my friend and since then these issues are happening.

Comment: It's possible that the USB key is corrupted (flash memory does have a finite number of write cycles), or the filesystem itself is corrupted.  What did your friend happen to do with the key, and what OS was he/she using?

Comment: I had this happen to one of my flash drives that's coming up on 10 years old. By this point I believe it is just at it's end of life.

Comment: I know this is super late but by any chance are you using a VM? if vm settings are set to use the plugged in device on the VM and not on the host machine it would happen just as you are foretelling your problem

Answer (score 1):

I have seen USB ports on some laptops that have sensitive connections. If the plug is jostled or wiggled it can often interrupt the connection. Best rule for me is: plug the USB drive in and don't touch the plug or move the cable till the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt formatting using `diskpart` within windows.

Use the follwing prompts to find out if the drive even has a volume in it. I recently had to send back a drive which was detected the volume wasn't in it. Meaning, the device was there but the "drive" in it wasn't there it was showing no volumes.

```
diskpart
list disk
```

Find your disk
select

```
select disk (x)
clean
create partition primary
format quick
assign
```

This will quickly format your drive and you can find out if its even working right. At this point if any of the steps fail you can go look for hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the pendrive itself is damaged. This could be some static electricity inside the pendrive or the usb connector itself was twisted and caused for a loose connection internally.

Keep in mind that temperature changes the shape of metal (metal expands when becoming hot) and the inside of a pendrive will warm up, which can cause for an already loose connection to become disconnected for a split second.

My recommendation is to replace the pendrive.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the USB port you are using is damaged so the easiest thing to do is to try several other ports. I would also try reinstalling the pendrives drivers or try it with another computer to see if that's the problem. If that's not it then it may be time to try to open the pendrives case and see if there isn't something you can fix or spend some money on a new pendrive. Perhaps check warranty and maybe research your pendrives model to see if there's similar issues.

Comment: OP States it happens cross-pc, so this is not a pc issue.